# How to create Custom Authorization attribute?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, custom-attributes

I am trying to implement a custom authorize attribute on my mvc4 app with parameters.

What I am trying to achieve is this:

```
[Authorize(Application == "Initialize,Start,..." , Topic == "foo1,foo2,foo3...")]
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
   //rest
}
```

The attribute should also be able to decorate the controller, not only methods

Comment: You probably mean to use `=` rather than `==`: unless you are comparing `Application` to `"Initialize,Start,..."`

Comment: you want an authorize attribute on class level? or what do you mena with "decorate the controller not only methods" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your [custom authorization attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707357%28v=vs.91%29.aspx):

```
public class UberAuthorizeAttr : System.Web.DomainServices.AuthorizationAttribute
{
    public string Application {get;set;}
    public string Topic {get;set;}

    public override bool Authorize(System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal principal)
    {
        // your custom behaviour
    }
}
```

Your controller:

```
[UberAuthorizeAttr(Application = "Initialize,Start,..." , Topic = "foo1,foo2,foo3...")]
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
   //rest
}
```

Is that what you are looking for?